# How to substitute a chars group with a single char and another chars group with another single char with a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, substitution, google-sheets-formula

My issue is the following:

In the string "`1@@@ 2### 3nd`"

I'm trying to replace the chars:

"`@@@`" with the single char "`♠`"

and the chars:

"`###`" with the single char "`♣`"

How can one substitute the single  "`@@@`" chars group with a single character (for example with "`♠`") and the chars group "`###`" with another single character (for example with "`♣`") with a single google sheets formula?

I tried this approach with the `REGEXREPLACE` Function:

```
=IFS(
AND(
LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"###",""))>0,
LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@@@",""))>0),
AND(
REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(###)","♠"),
REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(@@@)","♣")))
```

But it doesn't work.

I've tried also with the `SUBSTITUTE` function:

```
=IFS(
AND(
LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"###",""))>0,
LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@@@",""))>0),
AND(
SUBSTITUTE(A2,"###","♠"),
SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@@@","♣")))
```

I've found this answer [Multiple substitutions in a single text](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/multiple-substitutions-in-a-single-text) on a similar question, but I don't see how to apply it to my case.

The expected result should be this in the output cell:

"`1♠ 2♣ 3nd`"

Thanks a lot for your observations!

Comment: In your case, `REGEXREPLACE(A2,"@@@(.*?)###","♠$1♣")` will work, but in general, with RE2, you canot use conditional replacement patterns.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew ! it works great also! I will study how and come back if need be. Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A17, "@@@", "♠"), "###", "♣")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A17, "@@@", "♠"), "###", "♣")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks @player0 for that one again. You rock! I couldn't see it was possible to embed it to achieve the result. I will need to learn to embed formulas  and see how it work. It always seems a bit counter intuitive because of the cell reference to be embedded twice.

Comment: I see it now, the cell reference needs to be referred to once only for the 2 formulas, and we do it from the embedded one! Thanks again. Be well!